# Pyspark code to insert dataframe data into SQL Server or Oracle database using multiple connections

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

We have a dataframe with 1 billion records and we want to insert them into sql server first and then to oracle.

We plan to insert data into sql server using multiple connections so that data insert will be faster (parallelism)  and then we will do the same to oracle.

How to do this using multiple connections?

Comment: No one will do your work for you. You need to show some proof of the attempt you have made at achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:
Step 1: Partition the DataFrame

```py
num_partitions = 10 
partitions = dataframe.randomSplit([1.0] * num_partitions)
```

Step 2: Define Insert Function for SQL Server & Oracle

```py
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

def insert_to_sql_server(df: DataFrame):
    jdbc_url = "jdbc:sqlserver://YOUR_SQL_SERVER_HOST:1433;databaseName=YOUR_DB_NAME;"
    properties = {
        "user": "YOUR_USERNAME",
        "password": "YOUR_PASSWORD",
        "driver": "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    }
    df.write.jdbc(jdbc_url, "YOUR_TABLE_NAME", mode="append", properties=properties)

def insert_to_oracle(df: DataFrame):
    jdbc_url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@YOUR_ORACLE_HOST:1521:YOUR_SID"
    properties = {
        "user": "YOUR_USERNAME",
        "password": "YOUR_PASSWORD",
        "driver": "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    }
    df.write.jdbc(jdbc_url, "YOUR_TABLE_NAME", mode="append", properties=properties)
```

Step 3: Parallel Insert using ThreadPool

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_partitions) as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(insert_to_sql_server, partition) for partition in partitions]
    for future in futures:
        future.result()

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_partitions) as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(insert_to_oracle, partition) for partition in partitions]
    # Ensure all futures are done
    for future in futures:
        future.result()
```